# Opening 'Nfc Manager'. Flutter NFC manager

Tags: flutter

I have this problem, I am using Xiaomi redmi 8pro device for debuging my app and,i have found this problem, whan i scan the tag it opens an system app 'NFC Services', and it dosent trigger my code

Here is the code for widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
import 'package:nfc_manager/nfc_manager.dart';

class NfcWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title1;
  final String description1;
  final String description2;
  final int state1;
  final String user;

  const NfcWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.description1,
    required this.description2,
    required this.title1,
    required this.state1,
    required this.user,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NfcWidget> createState() => NfcWidgetState();
}

class NfcWidgetState extends State<NfcWidget> {
  String _tagId = '';
  bool _isListening = false;
  bool _isDone = false;
  late Stream<NfcTag> _tagStream;

  Future<void> android1() async {
    List<String> _id = App().getValue('info/tags') as List<String>;
    await NfcManager.instance.startSession(onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
      var tagId = tag.data['nfca']['identifier'];
      if (_id.contains(tagId)) {
        print('Susscesfully indentefied.');
        setState(() {
          _isDone = true;
        });
      }
      print(
          '------------------------------------------------------ ${tagId.toString() == '[4, 36, 97, 98, 236, 107, 129]'}');
      // setState(() {
      //   _tagId = tagId;
      // });
    });
  }

  void startFun() {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      android1();
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      // iOS-specific code
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startFun();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ( code )
  }
}
```

And yes i have all permissions in AndriodManifest.xml